# Проверить наличие строки в массиве

Tags: android, arraylist

Есть массив
ArrayList st = new ArrayList();
В него добавляются записи через .add . Как узнать или есть в нем первая  запись. Делаю так if (st.get(0)==null) - выбивает ошибку.

Comment: Когда возникают вопросы по классам из стандарной библиотеки то лучше воспользоваться официальной документацией -http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
st.isEmpty()
```

Возвращает true если массив пустой. Если пойти дальше и посмотреть реализацию в исходниках, то можно увидеть следующее

```
return array.size == 0
```

Можно использовать какой угодно метод, разницы нет.

Comment: ещё есть хорошая функция .contains(String или Object, в зависимости от содержимого массива)

Answer (score 0):

В нужном месте поставьте отладочную печать в виде:

```
System.out.println("Длина массива = " + st.size());
```

и сразу увидите сколько записей уже есть в массиве. Если печатает "0", то массив пуст.